# Magento 2 product list sorting

Tags: sorting, magento2

I see that in Magento 2 something changed in the way the page behaves when sorting a product list page or when the number of products visible per page is changed.
In Magento 1 there were parameters added to the url for sorting:

`http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/shirts.html`?**dir=asc&order=price**
`http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/shirts.html`?**dir=asc&limit=24&order=price**

but In magento 2 the sorting and page limit is changed via a POST request.
When I was a 'web development' student I learned that all filtering and sorting should be done via GET, for a better user experience.
This way the user can bookmark a list of 'things' already sorted, or share a link with the list filtered and sorted.

Any good reason why this is not used anymore in Magento 2? And is it worth sacrificing a bit of the customer experience for what ever reason that might be?

Comment: good remark, was wondering the same, I see no reason why they should use posts :|

Comment: For right cache handling?

Comment: @Amasty. Can you explain a bit? Also feel free to add your explanation as an answer.

Comment: You should raise an [issue at github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues) before it's too late to change.

Comment: @clockworkgeek. Done: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/656

Comment: I think it would also mess up proxy level caching.

Comment: POST is never cached (at least it should not). So doing sorting via POST is a really bad idea

Comment: @Marius, its only my guess based on the discussion with some core team devs. They are refactoring fpc now, and may be it is connected somehow

Comment: @Amasty. but is this a bug or a feature. If it's a feature I think I can do without it :).

Comment: Looks like they've made the change :-) http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/shirts.html?dir=asc&order=price

Comment: @moose. NO they didn't. the demo is for magento 1.9. The question is for Magento 2.

Comment: Doh. :P Awks. Well, let's hope you get a reply on the ticket you opened.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to a pre release version of Magento, more info here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request arguments are cut to avoid possible DOS attacks. So filter modifications are made with POST.

But I really think that you should create a ticket on github to fix this.

Comment: Thanks Anton. I already added a ticket: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/656 . I really don't like this POST approach.

Comment: I think usability, and in this case, ability to SHARE the link is very important.

Comment: Now it's back to post request :)

Answer (score 0):

> I learned that all filtering and sorting should be done via GET, for a better user experience.

You learned wrong first of all. there is not relation with Get method to sorting for good performance. Post decrease the chances of hack.

Comment: I see your point. It's something similar to what Anton said. I guess I have to look up my "teacher" and show him this. On the other hand, you should always sanitize your queries to avoid hacks.